# PHP stream_copy_to_stream generates leading and trailing garbage corrupting content of the stream

Tags: php, zend-framework, stream

I am trying to forward image from one server to another. Thanks to ZF2 it is not that easy as it should be. What I have already is below. As a result, the image is corrupted - firebug says that there is no response content. I can `echo` stream content and it looks fine (a lot of artifacts etc means that image has been downloaded correctly) 
So how to return content that I have in stream as an image? Maybe there is some corruption due badly handled streams?(I am not a php programmer)

```
    $response = new \Zend\Http\Response\Stream();
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
    $headers->addHeaders(array(
        'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ));
    $response->setHeaders($headers);
    $fh = @fopen('php://memory', 'wr');
    $count = stream_copy_to_stream(fopen($url, 'r'), $fh); // URL is OK if I paste it into browser - got image
    rewind($fh);
    //  echo stream_get_contents($fh); // it would look like garbage but means that image is downloaded
    $response->setStream($fh);
    return $response;
```

**EDIT**:
This is for sure PHP stream handling issue. I have compared downloaded content with original image, and I have found out, that there is some kind of leading and trailing garbage in file. Downloaded content starts with `0D 0A` whitch is carrage return. Where did that come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to my issue. The point was indeed in leading `0D 0A`. Accidently I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418670/php-force-download-return-corrupted-file) SO topic about outputing currupted files. All i needed to do is to remove `?>` from end of source of my controller, and leading new line is gone. I dont't understand why this even get to the output in all. Whith all of that i think that PHP... well you know what. It just should be gone from IT scene IMHO. Anyway 
`sqrt(-1) loves php === so_true)`